# How to treat wrong query params in the URL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, yup

I'm making an Next.js web app and I use the URL Params to query some information (limit, page number, order, etc).

But I don't know what would be a good way of treating bad inputs from the user.

At the moment I use **Yup** to validate and sanitize the inputs before using them, but the wrong values remain in the URL.

Should I do a router.replace to the same path but just adding the right query params? or is it better to show an error indicating that the values entered are not allowed?

Imagine there's a `orderBy` param that only allow the values `name`, `brand` or `count` and the user enters in the url `orderBy=year` with yup I just transform the value of order by to undefined, so the field is not sent in the fetch call. But the url will be still showing `https://xxxxx?orderBy=year`